# Logging size of filtered stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I want this stream to throw an exception if there are more than 1 results that survive the filter. Is there any way to achieve this?

One idea is to use `.count()`, but I'll have to create the stream again.

```
Optional<Result> filteredresultSet = results.stream()
        .filter(c -> c.equals("TOMATO))
        .findAny();
```

Comment: Are third-party libraries acceptable?  This sounds like a perfect job for Guava's [`MoreCollectors.toOptional()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/MoreCollectors.html#toOptional--).

Comment: Yeah! This totally works!

As a side question, what if I only want to log the issue, and not throw an exception?

Comment: You can always catch the exception and log instead...

Comment: Of course... wasn't thinking. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `findAny()` by `reduce()` and throw an exception in the accumulator:

```
Optional<String> filteredresultSet = results.stream()
                                            .filter("TOMATO"::equals)
                                            .reduce((s1, s2) -> {
                                                throw new MyException();
                                            });
```

An alternative to find out exactly how many elements are left and still retrieve the first one is to use a small array or custom object to store the count and first element:

```
results.stream().filter("TOMATO"::equals).collect(Container::new, (c, e) -> {
    c.count++;
    if (c.value == null)
    {
        c.value = e;
    }
}, (c1, c2) -> c1.count += c2.count);
```

This would return you an instance of `Container`, or `null` if the stream is empty. You can then check the `count` and return an `Optional` of the `value`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use `.limit(2)` on the stream to short-circuit after two matches and then collect to a list or array.

```
List<Result> filtered = results.stream()
    .filter(c -> c.equals("TOMATO"))
    .limit(2)   // we don't need to know if there are more than 2 matches
    .collect(toList());

if (filtered.size() > 1) {
    // throw or log
}

return filtered.isEmpty() ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(filtered.get(0));
```